# Accessing React Elements (not components) for re-rendering

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, components

The code looks something like this:

```
renderComponents : function (overlay) {
    var rtnOne = this.renderOne ('a'); // returns React Components
    var rtnTwo = this.renderTwo ('b'); // returns React Components
    var rtnThr = this.renderThr ('c'); // returns React Components

    ReactDOM.render (
        React.createElement ('div',
            {className : 'bigMama'},
            rtnThr,
            React.createElement ('div',
                {className : 'littleMama'},
                rtnOne,
                rtnTwo
            )
        ),overlay)
    );
},
```

Now my thinking is that when I update a component through `rtnOne ()`, I have a function which does this. As you probably notice, I am appending the component to the element in DOM through its class, which is clearly wrong.

```
updateRtnOne : function (a) {
    var rtnOne : renderOne (a);  // returns updated React Components
    ReactDOM.render (rtnOne,,document.getElementsByClassName ('littleMama')[0];
    )
}
```

How can I store a `ref` to React `<div class='littleMama'></div>` so that I can pass the updated components from 'rtnOne ()' into it.
From my understanding, I cannot attach `ref` to basic React div elements (which are not components). How can I 'get' the `<div class='littleMama'></div>` so I can append the component to it?

Thanks

Comment: This is what you want something like Flux for or just simply throw away the components and re-render them on every change.

Comment: thanks Henrik. I am aware of Flux, and I AM re-rendering the component. However, I want to 'grab' the react element upon which the component will re-render.

Comment: Okay, what you want to do with it?

Comment: append the component onto the div (which has been created via React.createElement)

Comment: If you've already rendered it once, why not just do the exact same procedure but with new data?

Comment: Haha, thats what I am doing. However, notice in the code, Im wanting to update one set of components (the output of `var rtnOne = renderOne (a)`), Im wanting not to update the other SIBLING components of rtnOne component.